# Converting protected areas polygons into raster

Tags: raster, vector, aggregation

I am working with protected areas for vulnerability analysis, I have values of 1 for protected areas being vulnerable, and 2 to non-protected areas being less vulnerable. I have transformed this into a raster file.

My question is: for standardizing this data should I run the following equation: ( x - min(x) ) / ( max(x) - min(x) ) in order to aggregate this layer with other data?

Comment: What are your other layers? Are they continuous or discrete data? What range of values do they contain?

Comment: Well, my other layers are poverty index by commune with values from 1 to 6, 1 being the "poorest" communes, degraded land, 1 being land degraded and 2 non-degraded, I also have an original raster layer with temperature anomalies ranging from - 2 values to 14, and an Euclidean distance of roads. I believe my original vector data is discrete and my rasters are continuous right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, what specific analysis do you intend to perform on these data?

Comment: climate change vulnerability analysis

Comment: Which set of tools?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS, is that what you mean by tools?

Comment: Which tools in ArcGIS?

Comment: To convert vector to raste the tool is polygon to raster and then Raster calculator to do the formulas